# Copying GeoJSON data from S3 to Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, geospatial, geojson

I have a spatial data. It is `GeoJSON` format. I want to copy this data into `Redshift` from `S3`. So can you please help me to create table and copy the data into table. I want to know `copy` command.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift's `COPY` command currently supports ingestion of geometries from (hexadecimal) `WKB`/`EWKB` format only. We *currently* do not support ingestion from `GeoJSON`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/geospatial-overview.html

Alternatively, you can ingest the data in `WKT` format as `VARCHAR(MAX)` and then convert to `GEOMETRY` using the [`ST_GeomFromText()` function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/ST_GeomFromText-function.html). Using this method the `WKT` description of a geometry is limited to the 64KB max `VARCHAR` size.

More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/spatial-limitations.html